# Aerobe or facultative anaerobe organism that metabolizes acetate?

Tags: microbiology, metabolism, bacteriology, yeast, archaea

I'm assuming bacteria, but will take any suggestions.  Organism must survive primarily on the acetate (plus trace elements), but I can give/take electrons, if necessary.  Not interested in strict anaerobes.  I've tried *Shewanella oneidensis*, but have not succeeded in getting it to eat any acetate (just lactate).  Feel free to give journal refs.  Self-promotion won't be frowned upon if it's helpful.  :-)  Opportunity for joint pub, if successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try *Paracoccus denitrificans.*

Here is a study where acetate is used as the growth-limiting substrate: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.320.1692&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Here's the details of its version of acetate kinase: http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/A1B9S8

I'd be happy to collaborate with you further on this.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  In this paper, the acetate is only 0.34% (v/v).  Do you know if P. denitrificans can handle higher concentration, say 1% to 3%?  (Many organisms are killed by acetate, hence pickling to preserve food.)  Or is 0.3% its limit?

Comment: This study: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC182557/?page=1 has P. denitrificans at 1% v/v sodium acetate. I don't know how much higher it can go though.